# How to connect mapguide maestro to postgresql/postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis, mapguide

I’m trying to connect my database postgresql/postgis to mapguide maestro but it send me a error message.

Do you have some idea about this, or can you help me about how can I connect it with my database postgis? I’m using postgresql 9.4, mapguide open source 2.6.1 and mapguide maestro 6.0

[image]

Comment: Probably you just have to create the POSTGIS extension in the database: `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`

Comment: what?? can you explain me?

Comment: Connect to your database with a client (in example psql)  and execute the command above

Comment: yes i'm doing it but it can't compiled !!! have you use mapguide maestro?

Comment: Use [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) to connect to a PostgreSql database. Maybe a online tutorial can be useful for you: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably connecting to a PostgreSQL database without PostGIS installed.

Either install PostGIS to that database (e.g. `CREATE EXTENSION postgis`), or modify your connection settings to the correct host/port/dbname with an existing PostGIS installation.

Comment: excuse me but i have installed the postgis extension

Comment: @welliam a database enabled with postgis has `geometry_columns` but the error message says it not there (assuming that it was installed in a schema in your `search_path`, usually `public`). You might have installed it to one database and are connecting to another.